# Is there a way to create a private channel's SharePoint site?

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-teams

We currently have an issue when creating private channels on a team which was created using the "/teams" Graph API endpoint.

When adding a private channel from the Graph API, the SharePoint site associated to the channel is not provisioned. User needs to visit the "Files" tab in the MSTeams client for the site to be created.

We noticed that this is not the case when initially creating the Team from the MSTeam client or from the "/groups/{id}/team" endpoint (which is marked as being soon deprecated). Using either of those two methods to create the team, SharePoint sites are automatically created when adding a private channel.

We were wondering if this was the expected behaviour or a bug. It is an issue for us as we have no way to automate the creation of the private channel's site and thus we cannot copy files into the site as long as a user did not visit the "Files" tab.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I've found a workaround for this issue. It seems like if you first make a call to the filesFolder endpoint on the primaryChannel of the team (the General channel), then the site will be provisioned for a private channel created afterward.

Comment: Thanks for adding this answer. I second this. We made SP site creation behind a private channel work by performing these steps, even using application permissions. Albeit not certain that the creation is instantaneous, it does trigger some process such that the site gets created. Still, quite a black box.

Answer (score 4):

@odrouin - This is not expected behavior. We have bug created for this issue. Thanks for reaching out.

Comment: Can you please share the bug link?

Comment: Do you have any update on this issue? Because of it, we are still not able to upload files into a private channel until a user visits the "Files" tab of the channel.

Comment: Furthermore, when creating the team through the Teams UI first and then creating the private channel through the graph, we can get the /filesfolder right away without a problem. It's when creating the team using the graph then creating a private channel through the graph where is never works.