# Teams private channels - SPO Site Collection Language & Regional Settings

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-teams

## Issue

Currently private channel SPO Site Collections are created with the main Language taken from the SPO-RootSite. If you have multiple Languages in your Company this is not the best solution as a User would expect the Language and Regional-Settings to be taken from the main Teams-SPO-SiteCollection from where he created the private channel.

## What we Tested:

Trying to solve the issue by creating the site with Template TEAMCHANNEL#0 and RelatedGroupId set by using /_api/SPSiteManager/Create. The site get's created so we could also configure the Folder for the Channel but unfortunately clicking on the "Files" Tab in Teams then just creates a additional sitecollection with a "2" added to the Channelname in Url.

## Conclusion & Suggestion:

Unfortunately we found no working solution to have the Private Channel Sites in the expected language with correct regional settings (user recognizes it on displayed dates).

- It would be nice if SPO-Site Collections for Private-Channels would
  respect the Languagesettings of the Team they belong to.
- It would be very nice if we could trigger SPO Site Creation for private Teams
  channel in order to configure for example the document library (view
  / Columns)

Comment: This sounds like a feature request. Please raise a [user voice](https://microsoftteams.uservoice.com/) for this.

Comment: It's actually both a bug and a feature request. The Bug is already part of [link]https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60849505/is-there-a-way-to-create-a-private-channels-sharepoint-site and as such confirmed.

Comment: The Featurerequest in Uservoice will be found here [link]https://microsoftteams.uservoice.com/forums/555103-public/suggestions/40669984-have-sp-site-for-private-team-channel-respect-lang